# Aplicando Loop em elementos de uma Matriz (R)

Tags: r, loop, matriz

Seja a matriz abaixo criada a partir do commando

```
simu_matrix <- matrix(runif(25,0,1),nrow=5,ncol=5)

    V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
1   0.07357303  0.45524021  0.9352829   0.60466424  0.4725541
2   0.51018615  0.46044203  0.6975768   0.43135240  0.7924976
3   0.60578062  0.94756261  0.4729004   0.88412092  0.2425650
4   0.16868889  0.34543686  0.1628527   0.05012683  0.7320737
5   0.76139364  0.08249016  0.1384000   0.23841682  0.5925934
```

Eu transformei em uma nova matriz usando as seguintes regras :

- Se o valor for menor ou igual a 0.1 transforma em 1
- Se Valor for maior que 0.1 e menor ou igual a 0.4 transforma em 2
- Se o valor for maior que 0.4 e menor ou igual a 0.7 transforma em 3
- Se o valor for maior que 0.7 e menor ou igual a 0.9 transforma em 4
- O resto transforma em 5

A Matriz resultante foi :

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1   1   3   5   3   3
2   3   3   3   3   4
3   3   5   3   4   2
4   2   2   2   1   4
5   4   1   2   2   3
```

O codigo utilizado foi :

```
simu_bets <- apply(simu_matrix,2,function(x) 
ifelse(x<0.1,1,
       ifelse(x>0.1 & x<=0.4,2,
              ifelse(x>0.4 & x<=0.7,3,
                     ifelse(x>0.7 & x<=0.9,4,5)))))
```

Minha pergunta é, existe uma maneira melhor de obter o mesmo resultado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função `cut` para codificar os valores de acordo com o intervalo em que se encaixam, e então converta o resultado para número:

```r
c <- cut(simu_matrix, breaks=c(0.0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0))
matrix(as.numeric(c), nrow=5)
```

### Solução alternativa

```r
apply(simu_matrix, 1, 
  function(x) as.numeric(
    cut(x, breaks=c(0.0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0), labels=1:5)))
```

(obrigado a Carlos Cinelli pela dica do `labels`)

Comment: Muito bom, somente adicionaria a seguinte informação. Do jeito que está funciona porque a pergunta quer converter na ordem dos breaks. Mas caso ele quisesse colocar número ou textos arbitrários no lugar de números de 1 a 5, bastaria utilizar o parâmetro labels e usar `as.character` na hora de converter. Por exemplo, colocando em ordem inversa `c <- cut(simu_matrix, breaks=c(0.0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0), labels=5:1);
matrix(as.numeric(as.character(c)), nrow=5)`